# Outlook Rule - Move mail that is READ and Older than X days

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook 2010.
Want to create a rule that moves all mail from my inbox to another folder:

- Has been read
- Is older than X days

I was looking at Auto-archiving, but it does not seem to let me be this specific with my criteria.

Comment: Could someone forward this to Microsoft Outlook team?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this at the moment is to create a new Search Folder with custom criteria e.g with items modified on or before a certain date. I then right-click the folder and choose 'Delete All' which sends all items in the Search Folder to the bin.

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, because the messages are not moved to a folder, they are **only moved to the bin**.

Answer (score 7):

The search folders are the answer, however the OP asked about mail *older than* a particular date.  If you use "modified last week" then it shows everything within the last week and filters out things older than 1 week.  For the inverse that, use language like:

- 8 days ago
- 1 week ago
- etc...

[image]

Comment: Great, did not know that you can write natural language for the value!

Answer (score 4):

I had been looking for something similar.  I have to use a macro as auto-archive is disabled for my installation.  Here's what I came up with:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()
    ' this runs on app startup
    Const MSG_AGE_IN_DAYS = 7

    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oFilteredItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim oItem As MailItem
    Dim oDate As Date

    oDate = DateAdd("d", -MSG_AGE_IN_DAYS, Now())
    oDate = Format(oDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ' you can use this command to select a folder
    'Set oFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder

    Set oFolder = Me.Session.Folders.GetFirst

    ' shows all the folder names
    'For Each fldr In oFolder.Folders
    '    Debug.Print fldr.Name
    'Next fldr

    ' this was the sub-folder I wanted to cleanup.
    Set oFolder = oFolder.Folders("Storage").Folders("batch runs")

    Debug.Print "checking " & oFolder.FolderPath
    Debug.Print "for msgs older than " & oDate

    ' you can modify the filter to suit your needs
    Set oFilteredItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict("[Received] <= '" & oDate & "' And [Unread] = True")

    Debug.Print "removing " & oFilteredItems.Count & " items"

    While oFilteredItems.Count > 0
        Set oItem = oFilteredItems.GetFirst
        Debug.Print "   " & oItem.UnRead & " " & oItem.Subject

        ' the remove method permanently deletes the item.
        oFilteredItems.Remove 1
        'Debug.Print oFilteredItems.Count & " items left"
    Wend

    Debug.Print ". end"

    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFilteredItems = Nothing
    Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

This macro is attached to the last phase of the application's lifecycle; it runs when Outlook starts up.  You'll probably also want to sign it (and trust your signature) so you do get security complaints.

HTH

Comment: Should `oFilteredItems.GetFirst` be `oFilteredItems.GetNext`?

Answer (score 1):

For the upcoming researchers, i have done the following using Developer tools

```
    Public WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

    Sub Application_Startup()
        Set olItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    End Sub

    Private Sub olItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
        Dim deFolder As Folder
     
        'Ensure the email marked as read
        If TypeOf Item Is MailItem And Item.UnRead = False Then
     
        'Check the email subject and then move to specific folder
        'You can change these conditions and folders as per your needs
        If InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), "test") > 0 Then
           Set deFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Test")
           Item.Move deFolder
        End If
     
        If InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), "worklog") > 0 Then
           Set deFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("WorkLog")
           Item.Move deFolder
        End If
     
        If InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), "report") > 0 Then
           Set deFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Report")
           Item.Move deFolder
        End If
    End Sub
```

After that, you should digitally sign this code.
Use the built-in “Digital Certificates for VBA Projects” tool to create a new certificate.